# js - подменить левый клик мышью, кликом средней кнопки мыши

Tags: javascript, события

Как подменить левый клик мышью, кликом средней кнопки мыши (scroll), то есть жму левую кнопку но выполняется действие как при  клике средней кнопки мыши.

```
 e.preventDefault();
 var $link = $(this).find('a'),
 mouseEventMiddle = new MouseEvent( "click", { 
    "button": 1, 
     "which": 2 
 });

$link[0].dispatchEvent(mouseEventMiddle);
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function logMouse(e) {
  var evt = e.type;
  while (evt.length < 11) evt += ' ';
  console.log(evt + " which=" + e.which + " button=" + e.button);
  return false;
}

function cloneObject(obj) {
  var key, clone = {};
  for (key in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) clone[key] = obj[key];
  return clone;
}

$(".jaja").on("click", function(e) {
  var newE = cloneObject(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  newE.button = 1;
  newE.which = 2;
  newE.originalEvent.button = 1;
  newE.originalEvent.which = 2;
  newE.originalEvent.defaultPrevented = false;
  newE.isDefaultPrevented = false;


  console.log("newE:" + newE.button);
  console.log("e:" + e.button);
  console.log(newE.button === e.button);

  e = new MouseEvent("click", newE);
  console.log("Щёлк! И уже средняя кнопка");
  logMouse(e); // тут евент будет уже с другими значениями button и which, но все остальные поля будут сохранены благодаря копированию объекта
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onmousedown="return logMouse(event)" onmouseup="return logMouse(event)" onclick="return logMouse(event)" oncontextmenu="return logMouse(event)" ondblclick="return logMouse(event)" value="Кликни меня левой или правой кнопкой мыши" type="button">
<input class="jaja" type="button" value="Щелк">
```

У меня получилось только так - но оно не вызывает поведение средней мыши - только "иллюзия". Надо еще подумать как "подставить" поведение , чтобы появился значок "скрола" (который появляется при нажатии на среднюю кнопку)

Comment: а если поменять input class="jaja" на а class="jaja". если кликать по ссылке левой кнопкой откроиться новый таб и переключит на него, а если средней то откроит новый таб в фоне (не переключаеться на него).

Comment: Что-то у меня такой вариант не прокатил. Смена на ссылку (с href) хоть и меняет срабатываение левой кнопки, но не подменяет его событием нажатие средней. Надо искать дальше